# finding t for parametric equation tangent line

Tags: calculus, parametric

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

> Find the tangent line at the point (0,2)
>
> $$x=2 \, \cot(t)$$ $$y=2 \, \sin^2(t)$$ $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -2 \,
> > \sin^3(t) \, \cos(t)$$ The tangent line is: $$y-2=m(x-0)$$

$t$ isn't given, I have to find it. I've tried setting $x$ and $y$ equal to each other, and using $\cot^{-1}$ to find what sets $x$ equal to $0$, but I get the wrong number.

How do I find t? A photo is attached here:

[image]

Should I set $x = y$ or use $\cot^{-1}$ on x? How do I find $t$ given $x$ and $y$ so I can get the tangent line equation?

Comment: it would help if you gave some sort  of an image

Comment: t=pi/2 and dy/dx = 0 is the answer (its just a straight with no slope), but problem is I need to know how to find t. So I can do it for other questions

Comment: @user242559 there, uploaded a picture, but shouldn't be required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a parametric curve, a directing vector of the tangent line at a point $(x(t_0),y(t_0))$ is the first non-zero derived vector. Here the point $(0,2)$ is obtained for $t_0=\dfrac\pi2$, hence a directing vector for the tangent line is:
$$\Bigl(-\frac2{\sin^2t_0},4\sin t_0\cos t_0\Bigr)=(-2,0).$$

Hence the equation of the tangent line is $\;y=2$.

Comment: I still don't understand how you got pi/2, I only started the beginning of calc 3

Comment: I don't know what is cal 3, but to obtain $y=2$, you must have $\sin^2t=1$, which is the same as $\sin t=\pm 1$. This can be solved in mid school.

Comment: ok I think I got it now, i was finding t using x which was giving a divide by zero error

Answer (score 1):

At the point $(0,2)$, $\;\;x=2\cot t=0\implies\cos t=0$, so

$\;\;\;\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\sin^3 t\cos t =0$ and therefore $y=2$ is the tangent line.